# User needs to login first before accessing website

Tags: login

***In my application, users have to login first before accessing the website.***

So now what I am doing, I have created one custom login page.

How can I redirect a user to the login page if he/she is not logged in yet.

Should i customize wp-login.php for login? 
Which is better way, **1.** Redirect user to login page or **2.** wp-login.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following action to redirect all traffic to that login page. You will need to specify the page name and the page slug.

```
add_action('wp', 'wpse_41699_wp', 0);
function wpse_41699_wp(){
    if(is_page('Login'))
        return;
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $url = get_bloginfo('home').'/login';
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Also, you can download the plugin version for this answer [here](http://3-3.me/87QM).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, you can try something like this:

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/logged.php'); 
            } else {
                include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/nonlogged.php'); 
            }
 ?>
```

and of course, nonlogged.php may be a page, or you can use jquery to show a pop up or whatever